# Move to GeoLite2 Free

Tags: geoip, web-analytics, maxmind, awstats

I currently use GeoLite Free with my awstats  analytics. I would like to start using GeoLite2 Free. What do I need to do to move from GeolLite to GeoLite2? I am assuming the format changed, so something in awstats needs to change perhaps?

I use awstats 7.3 on a windows IIS 8.5 machine (if that makes a difference).

A step-by-step guide would be most excellent, as I have to confess I'm not highly conversant in IIS, or PHP, or the like.

Comment: This will be a start (for you or anyone answering): http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/whats-new-in-geoip2/